# Fetching a snapshot of all the contracts accessible on Etherscan

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan

I am trying to collect a large set of online contracts and came across the following statement in a research article:

[image]

Does anyone know how to access such a "snapshot of 25983 contracts"? Is it somehow hosted by Etherscan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the dates are between a fairly small range, this can be done looking at all the blocks in the time interval and selecting the transactions that result in contract creation. That will give you the addresses. It may sound like much, but this should be a matter of hours in terms of processing.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. From my understanding, it seems that they somehow obtained a snapshot from when Ethereum mainnet online until August 30 2018. Am I missed anything.

Comment: Indeed, I have been using Google Bigquery to fetech all the addresses of contracts from the mainnet creation date until 2018-12-31. The total number is about 2M and "unique" contracts (by checking the md5sum of contract bytecode) is about 160K. This seems very inconsistent with their data...

Comment: Yes, you are right, I miss read the text. However, ~25000 contracts sound like a small amount for the mainnet or testnet. It is still feasible to just let your code run through the blocks.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely doable. But I am just confused because even running through blocks and collect the "creation transaction", I could have a much larger dataset >> 25000. I am just wondering how come they got such a dataset...

Comment: can you share the link to that paper?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.06067.pdf  If you search "Etherscan" in the pdf..

Comment: Thanks for the link, the SmartCopy algorithm that they propose needs the ABI of the contracts. Therefore, they are limited to the contracts that are verified in Etherscan (those have the ABI available). This will reduce drastically the number of available contracts. You can check the list of 160K that you got and try to get the ABI from Etherscan API, that will give you the number of contracts that could have been used with SmartCopy.

Comment: I see! Yes, that reminds me the issue on ABI. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, it is not so easy to tell whether particular transaction crated contract or not.  It is also possible for one transaction to create several contracts.